# How to access the Utilities of Selenium Java Framework in various different projects?

Tags: java, selenium, github, frameworks

I have created a Selenium Java Framework with a proper folder structure. Basically my framework consists of few common utilities(page objects, reporting configurations and, driver initialization settings, etc.). This framework was developed to automate and validate web applications. We have a bunch of web applications in our organization that are common in nature and behavior. The Java framework that I have developed has some generic methods and page objects that can be utilized in all the web applications.

Now, I have pushed my framework to the Github. And, I want other teams in my organization also to use my framework. So, in my organization for each project, we create a new repo. Therefore, I wanted to know if by any chance my framework can be accessed by other teams of my organization in their projects.

I don't want anyone to clone my framework repo, add their tests, and push it back. As each project in my organization will have their own repo. Therefore, I simply want them to add my framework as a dependency in their project repo. And, when they clone their repo and do a maven build, they should be able to access the utilities of my framework. Please let me know if this is possible by any chance. Thanks! in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options.

**Option 1:**
Give read-only access to the outside your project users, so that they can extract and re-use the items from the framework without impact your code. Other teams can tailor the framework according to their needs (you can consider it as adv/ disadv)

**Option 2:**
Convert your framework into a jar and then share it with other teams. Ask them to use the jar. No Edits in framework possible.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I think both options that you have mentioned are good. But, I would like to know more about Option 1, could you please elaborate on the extraction and reusing one. I can make my project as read-only. But, how are the other teams going to refer to my framework from their repo?

Comment: Check this link that will guide you in setting up the teams and access levels. https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/access-permissions-on-github

Answer (score 2):

We are exactly doing the same thing (we are using option-2 as below). Other teams need to use it as a dependency in their pom.xml. Two ways to use the dependency in maven:

1. If your company has maven artifactory management system, you can publish your framework jar into that and ask the other teams to use it as a dependency in their pom.xml directly

Else,
2. You need to prepare a jar file, and the other teams need to use it as a dependency using system scope level as below:

```
<!-- Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.group></groupId>
            <artifactId>automation-framework</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${jar.location}</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

groupId, artifactId, and version are the details of your framework project.
Other teams can create a folder called `"libs"` in in their project, and store your framework's jar in there. That location will go here: ${jar.location}

Every time you make changes to your framework and build new jar, they need to update the jar file under `"libs"` folder.

In this way, they can use all your utilities, but can't modify or publish any tests into your project.

Answer (score -1):

You need to keep utils package and create all utils classes into that package and use it
In every projects you need to keep package for separate keeping utils classes